# How to add right side bar with local table of contents in Sphinx ReadTheDocs Theme?

Tags: python, html, material-design, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

Is there a way to configure a Sphinx project using the [`sphinx-rtd-theme`](https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to add an extra local table of contents side bar on the right similar to [`sphinx-material`](https://bashtage.github.io/sphinx-material/customization.html#configuration-options) theme? I find the extra sticky local side bar on the right to be very useful when navigating the current page.

Comment: Not out of the box. Anything is possible with enough time and ambition.